# Hsqldb with Slick and Hikaricp

Tags: scala, slick, hsqldb, akka-http

I am trying to implement HSQLDB instead of Mysql ,my rest is service implemented over akka-http , with slick and connection pooling by Hikari cp.
Earlier

```
    class HikariService(jdbcUrl: String,
                    dbUser: String,
                    dbPassword: String,slickProfile:String) extends DriverDataSource{

  private val hikariConfig = new HikariConfig()
  val jdbcurl: String = s"$jdbcUrl/db_name"
  hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcurl)
  hikariConfig.setUsername(dbUser)
  hikariConfig.setPassword(dbPassword)



  private val dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)

  val driver = if(slickProfile == "MySQL")
   slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile
  else slick.jdbc.HsqldbProfile

  import driver.api._

  val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource)

  db.createSession()
}
```

and my jdbc url for hsqldb is jdbc:hsqldb:file:/Users/abc/

Now I am able to see the logs generated in the abc dir which has the .log file which says 
`SET SCHEMA PUBLIC`
and all the tables are created using the schema as public.
Now when I use slick to query it throws me error

Error during processing of request:

```
'user lacks privilege or object not found: table_name in statement [select "id", "name", "type", "configuration", "description" from "table_name" ]
```

my slick connection looks like

```
trait EntityTable {

  protected val hikariService: HikariService

  import hikariService.driver.api._
  protected val enricher = TableQuery[Table_name]

  class Enricher(tag: Tag) extends Table[EnricherEntity](tag, "table_name") {
    def * = (id, name, `type`, description, configuration) <> ((EnricherEntity.apply _).tupled, EnricherEntity.unapply)

    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def `type` = column[String]("type")

    def description = column[Option[String]]("description")

    def configuration = column[String]("configuration")
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this

Comment: Is the db name really db_name, and the table name really table_name ? It kinda looks like you're missing some string interpolation here ^^

Comment: Please report the CREATE TABLE ...  statement in the .log file for this table.

Comment: `CREATE MEMORY TABLE "db_name"."table_name"("version_rank" INTEGER NOT NULL,"installed_rank" INTEGER NOT NULL,"version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,"type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,"checksum" INTEGER,"installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"installed_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,"success" BIT(1) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "schema_version_pk" PRIMARY KEY("version"))
`

Comment: @C4stor I have taken db_name and table_name as reference name to database and table respectively

Answer (score 0):

Your CREATE TABLE creates the table in a schema named "db_name". But your SELECT statement does not reference the schema. In this situation, the current default schema, called PUBLIC, is used for the SELECT statement. As there is no such table in the PUBLIC schema, the error is returned.

You can use 4 different methods.

1. rename the PUBLIC schema to "db_name" before you create the table.
2. change the default schema of the user to "db_name"
3. set the current schema for the connection to "db_name"
4. use the "PUBLIC" schema name instead of "db_name"